# Append notes to body (with formatting)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

This function

```
function appendiNote() { //appende tutte le note ma senza formattazione..
  var note = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFootnotes();

  for (var i = 0; i < note.length; i++){
    var par = note[i].getFootnoteContents();
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendParagraph((i+1)+par.getText());    
  }
```

appends all notes inside the body document, but the formatting of the gets lost ....how can I do it so it gets formatted as well (word by word, i need it to preserve italic and bold words)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footnotes are objects in Google, so you need to access each object and extract the string text. You need to use `.getFootnoteContents()` in conjunction with the `.copy()` method to copy the properties of the `Footnote`.

[More on the `copy` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footnote#copy())

Change your code to:

```js
function appendiNote() { 
  // Gets all footnotes in the document as an iterable array
  var notes = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFootnotes();

  // iterate through the notes array
  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    // for each item, get the contents of the object
    var note = notes[i].getFootnoteContents();

    // create a deep copy of the object, which includes styles.
    var par = note.getChild(0).copy();

    // Append the footnote, including styles, as a paragraph in the body of the doc.
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendParagraph(par);
}
```

Comment: That works but the author wanted also to add indexes in front of notes. Look at (i+1) part.